# Hyphenating a verse range

Tags: typography, hyphenation

I am typesetting verses using `bibleref` and sometimes verse ranges get cut in the end of lines. For example, in:

Jean 3.16-18

the cut might happen right after the "-" (which is actually typeset as `--`). Do you think it is proper for such ranges to be cut, or should this be prevented? Specifically, if you know French typography, is there a rule that says that such cuts should be prevented?

The manual from the French *Imprimerie Nationale* does specify that numbers (such as `5,25%` or `11h30`) should not be cut, but it doesn't talk about ranges.

**Disclaimer:** I know this question is more about typography (and I'm looking forward to the [typography SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5409/fonts-typography)), but I can't think of another good place to ask this right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After pondering the various cases of hyphenation of expressions using both words and numbers, I think the best for Bible verses is the following:

```
1 Jean 3.16-18 ; 20-22
```

where ";" is the only place where hyphenation would be allowed, as well as hyphenating "Jean" because it's a word.

As far as implementation goes, it turned out to be much easier than I'd have thought. Simply redefining macros in `bibleref.sty` does what I want:

```
% unbreakable space between book name and chapter
\renewcommand*{\BRbkchsep}{~}%
% protect en-dash to prevent hyphenation in verse range
\renewcommand*{\BRvrsep}{\mbox{--}\nobreak}%
% unbreakable space after commas
\renewcommand*{\BRchvsep}{,~}%
```

So you can have:

```
1~Co\-rin\-thiens~5.2\mbox{--}\nobreak6,~8\mbox{--}\nobreak10
```

but no other hyphenation point is allowed.

I will actually send the patch to the author since I think it should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the bible reference in \mbox. A personal command might be beneficial.

I wouldn't break a line at that point unless any alternative is worse. That is, I would try with \mbox and, if it doesn't work, with some slight rewording of the paragraph; then with \emergencystretch (recall to enclose the paragraph in a group

```
end of paragraph.

\begingroup\emergencystretch=3em
The paragraph that has problems ... \mbox{...} ...
\par\endgroup
```

If all fails, resort to leave the line break at the dash.

Comment: Thanks. However, the question was not how to do it but rather whether this should be done (hence the disclaimer about it being a typography question).

Comment: rewording is only fine when you're the author, which is not always my case.

Comment: @Raphink: then jump over that step.